# Scope of variables in function in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I am working in Ubuntu Shell, but i want it to work for UNIX also.
Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

func()
{
    x=42
}

x=9
func
echo $x
```

- Why is global `x` changed to 42 when i changed only local variable `x`
- Is in unix different rule for variable scopes?
- Is there a method how to set return value from `func` to global variable, which can be used later in code?

Thank you!

Comment: local/declare are the options to investigate

Comment: The answer to most basic bash questions can be found in the manual: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/124167/608639), [Defining common variables across multiple scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27226650/608639), [How to export a variable in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307120/608639), [How do I define a shell script variable to have scope outside of the script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8153923/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not programming Linux; you're actually writing a function for the shell program called bash. Enter `info bash` on the command line to get documentation for that. For any version of Unix, what happens on the command line depends on which type of shell you're running (there are many; `bash` is the default for most Linux systems).

Variables in a function which are not declared are global by default. As the comment stated, you can use `local` to mark the variable as local to the function.

Comment: Thank you!  
And about that return value, is there some method? 
Something with similar to `var=$(fun)`

Comment: It's a bit odd. You can print the result and then capture the result into a variable: `$ func() {   local x;   x="fred";   echo $x; };
$ wilma=$(func);
$ echo $wilma` which prints "fred"

Comment: Or, you can return an integer as an error code: `$ func() { return 42 }; func; ERR=$?; echo $ERR` which will print 42. (Note there has to be a newline between the return statement and the '}', which I can't include in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for answers :) It helped