# Unable to array values outside of function in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have the following script named run.sh:

```
#This is run.sh

prerequisite(){

config_file=./../config/config.sh
source $config_file

    echo "VAR1 inside prerequisite: $VAR1"
    echo "country currency inside prerequisite: $country_currency[@]"
}

LIST_OF_COUNTRIES=`cat country_list.txt`

transform() {
    local country="$@"
    prerequisite
    echo "VAR1 inside transform: $VAR1"
    echo "country currency inside transform: $country_currency[@]"
}

transform ${LIST_OF_COUNTRIES[@]} &
transformpid=$!

wait $transformpid

echo "Complete"
```

The content of my config.sh file is:

```
VAR1="value1"
declare -a country_currency=( "INR" "USD" "JPY" )
```

When I run my run.sh file, 
I get the following output:

```
VAR1 inside prerequisite: value1
country currency inside prerequisite: INR USD JPY

VAR1 inside transform: value1
country currency inside transform:
```

As I see from the output, the value of all the variables that I am sourcing from my config .sh file is getting fetching into the prerequisite function. 
Whereas the values in the array are not getting fetched into the transform function. This is just a small snippet of code. I am doing multiple calls to the prerequisite function to dynamically source the values in my actual code. What am I doing wrong over here? Isn't the scope of the variable and the array that I have declared, supposed to be the same?

Comment: Source the file outside both functions - right above the call to transform

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/124167/608639), [Defining common variables across multiple scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27226650/608639), [How to export a variable in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307120/608639), [How do I define a shell script variable to have scope outside of the script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8153923/608639), etc.

Comment: How are you getting output from the prerequisite functions when your script never calls it?